# Incremental Query Engine for Oracle/RDBMS

Tags: sql, oracle, join, etl

I am not sure if "incremental" is the correct word for this or not. I will go ahead with stating the problem.

I have two big tables, X and Y. 
Z is another table which is the join of X and Y.

```
Create Table Z as 
select X.col1, X.col2, Y.col2, Y.col3 
from X 
join Y on X.id=Y.id"
```

Now, whenever any value is updated in table X or Y, my data in Z should be refreshed.
There are two ways to do it:

1. Refresh Table Z explicitly at regular intervals.
   Cons are 1) data is not updated in real-time 2) the refresh which runs the join again took lot of time though only a field is changed.
2. Do incremental updates in table Z as per any change in X and Y.
   The possible benefit being that it is real-time and won't take much time to update as only concerned rows will be updated.

I am looking for any help/direction on how to implement 2) approach for Oracle or any other database?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are creating Z as a table rather than a materialized view?  Oracle already knows how to do an incremental refresh of a materialized view (assuming the query is as simple as you show and assuming you create materialized view logs on X and Y)

Comment: Agree, table Z should probably be a view instead of a table.  Not sure that it should be a materialized view, but maybe..

Comment: @justin and alex I "leveraged" your ideas into an answer...

Answer (score 3):

To turn comments (and implied answers) by Justin and Alex into an answer, you probably want to use a materialized view.  If you are not familiar with them, where data in a regular view does not physically exist, but is just returned from the data in the tables in the view definition, the materialized view creates a physical representation of the data, and that materialized view can be refreshed in a variety of ways.  I will refer to the join between table `X` and table `Y` (the "base tables") as table `Z` below, but `Z` might be a table, view, or materialized view:

As Alex alluded, there may be reasons why you may not want to use a materialized view, so let me mention some common reasons **not** to:

- The resulting materialized view would take up a large amount of physical disk space; such as when joining huge tables `X` and `Y` would create a huge table `Z`
- The base tables X and Y are updated frequently, and the table `Z` is not accessed as often as the base tables are updated

Again, the above are rash generalizations; you will want to test the various options.

Advantages of a materialized view instead of a real table `Z` or a view `Z` include:

- Fast access to the data compared to a view fetching data from the base tables
- A materialized view can be refreshed on a time-based schedule, or when data changes on the base tables, or by request.  Since you included the [etl](/questions/tagged/etl) tag, you could refresh the materialized view after a particular procedure or job runs.
- You can create materialized view logs on the base tables to speed up materialized view refreshes even more.
- If queries to table `Z` are frequent, a materialized view will *probably* be faster than a regular view.

So test several ways: your first two ways, and a regular view, and a materialized view.  If table `Z` does not need a lot of columns from the base table, a regular view may work.  If the join criteria yield a small number of rows, a materialized view may be the best.

References:

- Materialized View [Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#DWHSG008)
- Materialized View [Logs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#DWHSG8209)

Comment: on further reading, I found that Materialized Views support "Atomic Refresh" but it needs lot of pre-work like creating VIEW-LOG for each table. (Refer: https://danischnider.wordpress.com/2019/02/18/materialized-view-refresh-for-dummies/). The limitations of this approach for my usecase is that 1) i have almost 40-50 tables to join 2) updates should be reflected in table/view Z in real-time (<1 sec). Any idea?

Comment: 40 to 50 tables to join?  For one query, or do you have around 20 to 25 queries that join two tables?  I assume the latter....  Can you edit your question and give a little more detail on how many rows (on average) in table X and table Y, and expected number of rows on table Z?  If you want response time less than one second, you have to do some work up front.